# Конвертирование .jpg в .pdf

Tags: linux, bash, pdf, imagemagick

Учусь. Часто возникает необходимость склеить подряд jpg в pdf и отправить преподу отчет.
Сейчас пользуюсь пакетом imagemagick - `convert *.jpg report.pdf` и в большинстве случаев более чем устраивает, но либо я совсем плохо читаю `--help`, либо все таки нет там возможности более гибко проаодить сею процедуру. Первое, что никак не удается победить:
1. Имеется 2(две) .jpg (2268 × 4032, **вертикальные фото**) если их прямо засунуть вышеупомянутой командой в pdf, то они расположаться **горизонтально** на странице, по фотке на страницу(так  идолжно быть, в справке по команде указано, чтоv`convert` специально картинки располагает так, чтобы максимально заполнить страницу).
**Главный вопрос** - как заставить его пихать фотографии прямо как есть(вертикально) и оставшееся место заполнять белым?
Доп. Вопрос - быть может вы сталкиваетесь/сталкивались регулярно с похожими задачами и подскажите тулзу поудобнее?
P.S. Последний, наиболее не предпочтительный вариант это настряпать самому какой-нибудь всемогущий костыль на C, C++, Java, Kotlin, Python (все, что знаю), задача плевая, но слишком мешает лень, тем не менее, если подскажите какие-нибудь интересные варианты или библиотеки (тк побайтово писать в файл начиная с шапки ну совсем убьет лень) - буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то для этих целей лучше использовать tex

Comment: Каждый jpeg отдельно в pdf, а потом с помощью pdf2pdf или ещё десятка разных утилит склеиваете в многостраничный pdf. P.S. Я более чем уверен, что есть способы элегантнее. И еяпп, pdf не умеет jpeg, конвертер пережимает в подходящий формат компрессии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извиняюсь, плохо читаю мануалы..
Запуск команды с ключом `-auto-orient` **полностью решает** поставленную задачу.

---

Также, частные случаи вышеупомянутой задачи решают ключи:

- transform
- transpose
- transverse
- trim